# Balancing a multilabel dataset

Tags: pytorch, nlp, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset that contains email texts and their corresponding labels. Each email can have multiple labels, making it a multilabel problem. I used multi-hot encoding for labels, so they look like [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], where 1 indicates that an email belongs to that class. However, my data is imbalanced, and some label combinations barely occur in the dataset, which makes my LSTM biased towards the majority classes.

I tried a weighted loss function by specifying pos_weight for BCEWithLogitsLoss, but that doesn’t seem to help. What are some balancing techniques that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try over-sampling or under-sampling to balance your dataset by using  the imblearn library in Python, which provides several oversampling and under-sampling techniques.

-Other balancing techniques you can use are :

1)Cluster-based under-sampling: Cluster-based under-sampling involves grouping the samples based on their similarity and removing some clusters to balance the dataset. This approach can be useful when the majority classes have a large number of samples that are similar to each other.

2)Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique (SMOTE): SMOTE is a popular oversampling technique that synthesizes new samples for the minority classes

3)Adaptive Synthetic Sampling (ADASYN): ADASYN is another oversampling technique that synthesizes new samples for the minority classes